# how to search multiple tables according to criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I want you to give me a hand. My idea is to be able to search according to criteria. these criteria are related tables.
where I have a projects table and this has a relationship with the populations and departments table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpVF6.png)

```
table projects
id |  name          | year  |
4  | proyect 1      | 2019  |
6  | proyect 2      | 2020  |

table populations_project

id | project_id    | name  |
1  | 4             | rural |
2  | 6             | city  |

table departments_project

id | project_id    | name        |
1  | 4             | florida     |
2  | 6             | california  |

the result

p_p =  populations_project
d_p = departments_project

result projects
id |  name          | year  | p_p   | p_p  | d_p_id | d_name  
4  | proyect 1      | 2019  | City |  1   |  1     |  florida
```

search
**find 2019 and florida  and city**

and my inicial sql is

```
SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE  year BETWEEN '2019' and '2020'
```

with this filter the year and the table projects

[see the image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpVF6.png)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you for showing us sample table data. Now please also also show us the expected result. And what exactly is it you have problems with? Have you even tried to write a query? What does it look like now? Where are you stuck?

Comment: sorry, I already added the expected result

Comment: the idea is to be able to obtain the projects they want from the year 2019 and contain the population "city" and the department "california".
The initial thing I have done is the BETWEEN '$ yearIn' and '$ yearOff'

Comment: a project can have multiple populations or multiple departments

Comment: But the task, the sample data and the sample result you are showing don't match. For the sample data I'd expect no result row, because no project matches all 2019 and florida and city. Or are you looking for 2019 and/or florida and/or city? Then I'd expect both projetcs to match. Please edit your request so that your example matches the description.

Comment: And have you been given the task without knowing that you can *join* tables? This is hard to imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```html
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.year, pp.name, pp.id, dp.id, dp.name
FROM projects p
 join departments_projects dp on p.id = dp.project_id
 join population_projects pp on p.id = pp.project_id
WHERE
 dp.name='florida' AND 
 pp.name='city' AND
 p.year = 2019;
```

Let us know if it returns your expected result

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need join table?

```
select * 
from projects p
join populations_project pp on p.id = pp.project_id
join departments_project dp on p.id = dp.project_id
where dp.name = 'florida' 
  and pp.name = 'city' 
  and p.year BETWEEN '2019' and '2020'
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20c410/7)

In you data for `proyect 1` and `populations_project.name = 'city'` and `departments_project.name = 'florida'` doesn't exists relation